# Remove Paypal Credit from Magento checkout

Tags: paypal, magento-1.9

Have express checkout on magento 1.9.4.3, the checkout comes with various options for paypal, 1 being paypal credit.

There is no option in settings to disable this, and also it appears twice.

How do I delete the code to get rid of any paypal credit mentions.

Thanks